# Access application running on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm currently learning kubernetes and started to deploy ELK stack on a minikube cluster (running on a **linux EC2** instance), though i was able to run all the objects successfully, I'm not able to access any of the tool from my **windows browser**, looking for some inputs on how to access all below exposed ports from my windows browser.

Cluster details:

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/elasticsearch-deployment-5c7d5cb5fb-g55ft   1/1     Running   0          3m43s
pod/kibana-deployment-76d8744864-ddx4h          1/1     Running   0          3m43s
pod/logstash-deployment-56849fcd7b-bjlzf        1/1     Running   0          3m43s

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/elasticsearch-service   ClusterIP   XX.XX.XX.XX      <none>        9200/TCP            3m43s
service/kibana-service          ClusterIP   XX.XX.XX.XX      <none>        5601/TCP            3m43s
service/kubernetes              ClusterIP   XX.XX.XX.XX      <none>        443/TCP             5m15s
service/logstash-service        ClusterIP   10.XX.XX.XX      <none>        9600/TCP,5044/TCP   3m43s

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/elasticsearch-deployment   1/1     1            1           3m43s
deployment.apps/kibana-deployment          1/1     1            1           3m43s
deployment.apps/logstash-deployment        1/1     1            1           3m43s

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/elasticsearch-deployment-5c7d5cb5fb   1         1         1       3m43s
replicaset.apps/kibana-deployment-76d8744864          1         1         1       3m43s
replicaset.apps/logstash-deployment-56849fcd7b        1         1         1       3m43s
```

Note: I also tried to run all the above services as NodePort and using the `minikube ip` i was able hit curl commands to check the status of the application, but still not able to access any of it via my browser

Comment: what error you get? Did the curl from the same system from where you trying to access via browser worked?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu

Below is the powershell output:
`PS C:\Users\Alpha123> Invoke-WebRequest http://<minikubeip>:5601`
`Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server`

Below is the curl output while using the ClusterIP Service:
`alpha@myEC2vm:~$ curl http://<minikube ip>:5601/api/status`
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to <minikube ip> port 5601: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want expose anything outside the cluster you need to user `service type`:
[NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) or use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). If you will check [Minikube documentaton](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/), you will find that `Minikube` supports all those types.

If you thought about `LoadBalancer`, you can use [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel).

When you are using `cloud environment` and non standard ports, you should check `firewall rules` to check if port/traffic is open.

Regarding error from comment, it seems that you have issue with `Kibana` port `5601`.

Did you check similar threads like [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-1-x-x-x-port-5601-connection-refused/146848) or [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-port-5601-connection-refused/71809)? If this won't be helpful, please provide Kibana configuration.

Comment: Hi @Pjoter, Actually i am more interested to know on how i can access my ELK Stack from my windows browser?
By running the cluster on NodePort service, i'll be only able to access the stack from the VM itself (using `minikube ip`), but am looking for info on how i can access the stack using my `VM's Public IP` on my windows machine?
Note: I'm on windows and connecting to the linux VM using PuTTY, so i'm looking for  guidance on how i can access the stack using VM's public IP

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, i've used ClusterIP and Ingress Nginx combination and was successfully able to curl from the VM; is there any way i can route the http requests to my public IP of the VM to this minikube IP?

Comment: i used nginx to proxy the requests to my VM to minikube

Comment: I guess answer about minikube redirecting using nginx was provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737619/how-to-use-nginx-ingress-to-route-traffic-based-on-port)

Answer (score 0):

did you check just a normal port-forward instead of minikube ip, and expose. Those didnt work for me neither.

something like this may would help.

kubectl port-forward deployment/kibana-kibana 5601