# How to use nginx ingress to route traffic based on port

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm currently working on deploying ELK stack on kubernetes cluster, i was successfully able to use ClusterIP service and nginx-ingress on minikube to route inbound http traffic to kibana (5601 port), need inputs on how i can route traffic based on inbound port rather than path?

Using below Ingress object declaration, i was successfully able to connect to my kibana deployment, but how can i access other tools stack exposed on different ports (9200, 5044, 9600)?

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: ingress-service
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-service
          servicePort: 5601
```

CUrl'ing `minikube ip` on default 80 port returns valid response

```
# curl http://<minikube-ip>/api/status
{"name":"kibana",....}
```

Note: i would not want to use NodePort, but would like to know if nodeport is the only way we can achieve the above?

Comment: You can try use [multiple paths](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#path-priority). I will prepare answer in a while with description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have [minikube](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) and `minikube ingress addon` enabled:

```
$ minikube addons list | grep ingress
| ingress                     | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | enabled ✅   |
```

Just as reminder:

`targetPort`: is the port the container accepts traffic on (port where application runs inside the pod).

`port`: is the abstracted `Service port`, which can be any port other pods use to access the `Service`.

Please keep in mind that if your container will not be listening port specified in `targetPort` you will not be able to connect to the pod.
Also remember about firewall configuration to allow traffic.

As for example I've used this yamls:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-one
spec:
  selector:
    key: application-1
  ports:
    - port: 81
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: application-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: application-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-two
spec:
  selector:
    key: application-2
  ports:
    - port: 82
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: application-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: application-2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello2
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: service-one
          servicePort: 81
      - path: /hello2
        backend:
          serviceName: service-two
          servicePort: 82

service/service-one created
deployment.apps/deployment-1 created
service/service-two created
deployment.apps/deployment-2 created
Warning: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress created
```

> Warning: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress

Please keep in mind that soon Minikube will change `apiVersion` as per warning above.

Below output of this configuration:

```yaml
$ curl http://172.17.0.3/hello
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-2l4cp
minikube-ubuntu18:~$ curl http://172.17.0.3/hello2
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-5dvbx
```

You could use:

```yaml
      paths:
      - path: /elasticsearch
        backend:
          serviceName: elasticsearch-service
          servicePort: 100
      - path: /anotherservice
        backend:
          serviceName: another-service
          servicePort: 101
```

Where service would looks like:

```yaml
  name: elasticsearch-service
  ...
  ports:
    - port: 100
      targetPort: 9200
  ---
  name: another-service
  ...
  ports:
    - port: 101
      targetPort: 5044
```

However, if you would need more advanced `path` configuration you can also use [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). Also you can use `default backend` to redirect to specific service.

More information about accessing Minikube you can find in [Minikube documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).

Is it what you were looking for or something different?